# Unity. Проблема с анимацией

Tags: c#, анимация, unity3d

Делаю анимацию движения для персонажа .Сама анимация бега - работает. Создаю триггер перехода в анимацию прыжка, а так-же bool нахождение в воздухе. Но из кода почему-то не вызывается Триггер и bool на true тоже не меняется.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float JumpForce = 3f;
    public bool inAir;
    Animator animator;
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
```

```
    void Update()
    {
        
        inAir = gameObject.transform.position.y >= 3.3;
        if(gameObject.name == "Main hero") { 
        animator.SetBool("InAir",inAir);

        }
        
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && !inAir) {

            jump();
            animator.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Так, решил, проблема была в том что я в аниматоре в поле названия триггера добавил один пробел в конце